# How to modify dynamically the fee of a transaction?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, json-rpc

I want to modify dynamically the fee for each transaction made by the users who use my website. I calculate the fees dynamically but I don't know how can I apply that custom fee for each user. I am trying it in the following way:

```
$this->bitcoin->settxfee($fee);
$output = $this->bitcoin->sendtoaddress($toAddress, $amount);
```

If someone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful

Answer (score -1):

You can only do this if you set the RBF bit on the original transaction.

Comment: Hey, don't hate the player. Hate the game. 